# Append to a serialization object

Tags: r

Let's say that you have a data object saved to rds. Is there a way to append (like `c()`, or `rbind`, `cbind`) to the saved object without explicitly loading the original? Given the assumption that the object will either be of the same type or have the same attributes?

```
# psuedo-code
a_list <- list(x = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),y = c(6,5,4,3,2,1))
saveRDS(a_list, "path/to/file.rds")

# empty workspace
a_new_lsit <- list(z = c(3,2,1,6,5,4))
appendRDS(a_new_list, "path/to/file.rds")
```

To clarify, `a_list` would not be in the workspace. That's the point of this question - I'd like to append to a serialized object without explicitly loading it.

Comment: There's some relevant information [here](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#Serialization-Formats). It looks like R encodes certain data (length, object type, object attributes) in the first dozen or so bits of the serialized file, so presumably appending (`cbind`ing, `rbind`ing, etc...) another object would mean the changing those "meta" bits in the original file.

Comment: If you have the right tools on your system you can try [playing around](https://gist.github.com/nathan-russell/1e5ee66bd767f09088da) with this, but even in the simplest case (atomic vectors), appending objects as you describe in your question would involve more than simple appending a file, so I would guess that it isn't worth the trouble of creating such a function.

Comment: Yes, my suspicion is that this isn't be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible due to the binary format of the object.

Answer (score 0):

```
saveRDS(c(a_list,list(z = c(3,2,1,6,5,4)) ), "path/to/file.rds")
```

Comment: To clarify, `a_list` would not be in the workspace. That's the point of this question - I'd like to append to a serialized object without explicitly loading it.